# Android facebook where is the share button

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, android-facebook, facebook-sdk-3.0

I want to share some text on facebook from my android sdk, I can interact with facebook from my sdk as I want, but I could not find the `share` logo, that blue logo which users have already familiar with.

I am sure it is something in the `xml` but i don't know what it is.

#### Edit

This is the logo which I am looking for.

#### Thanks in advance

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to follow guidelines and how Android UI works, you might want to use the menu style (grey) icon that you can put in ActionBar (the one you linked is not meant for an ActionBar)

I would suggest stuff like this: http://www.androidicons.com/

[image]